# Null pointer reference in fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, webview

I have uploaded my app on playstore and it got about 600 downloads in a week ,the problem is that there are about 20 instances of crashing that I have seen on firebase.I tested my app on various phones but it didn't occur to me but about 20 crashes have been reported.I have seen the code multiple times and also searched and read about problem but couldn't find a solution.

Code is of about 150 lines so,Link-https://www.writeurl.com/text/6pydtz3aictqplzk3efs/eq3n03k23ww11wflkzis/vgarvxzcog2ldc96dgei

Actually I am loading a webView here is my code in fragment-

I have 3 fragments and the error reported is-

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources 

android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
android.widget.Toast.<init> (Toast.java:102)

android.widget.Toast.makeText (Toast.java:266)

com.package.a$6.onReceivedError ()
com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onReceivedError2 (WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:260)

org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleM essage (AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:38)

android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)

android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:157)

android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5571)

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:745)

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:635).
```

Please give a word.

Comment: Man If it would be duplicate I won't be posting it here,atleast see the code

Comment: first you provide your code in question not a link.

Comment: please provide all stack trace

Comment: error is due to Toast inside RecievedError method

Comment: Probably you're doing an Async call and when it comes back, the context you're using to display the Toast doesn't exist anymore (the Activity/Fragment/... has been destroyed)